# Extends Frame class in main method's class

Tags: java, inheritance, awt, frame, composition

Today when I was reading my lecture notes, I don't understand what the purpose of `extends` is in this context. Consider this code:

```
import java.net.*;    
import java.awt.*;

public class QueenApl extends Frame{ // Why extends??
  Image card;

public static void main(String[] args){
    QueenApl f = new QueenApl();
    f.show();    
}

public QueenApl(){
    setSize(400,400);
    try{
      URL u = new URL("file:/c:/windows/desktop/carn4.jpg");
      card=getToolkit().getImage(u); //Why getToolkit can be used directly?
    }catch(MalformedURLException e){
     System.out.println("Error in URL!"); System.exit(1);
    }  
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
      g.drawImage(card,120,50,this);
    }   
}
```

1. Why does the main method class extend the `Frame` class? Why isn't `Frame` created inside the main method or as an instance variable of class `QueenApl`? Like this:

   ```
   Frame someobj = new Frame(argument or none);
   ```
2. Why can `getToolkit()` be used directly without appending the `classname.` in front of it? Is it because this method is in the class `Frame` and since the main method class inherits `Frame`, we can use the method directly?

Comment: not, not, not, don't extends JFrame, everything this way is simple and wrong

Comment: I try to google about why extending Jframe is a big mistake too

Comment: for displaying an Image to put JPanel to JFrame, override PreferredSize for JPanel and to use paintComponent instead of paint

Comment: *"Today when I was reading my lecture notes, .. Consider this code:"* Wait, what - did this code come from the instructor?  It is rubbish code from start to end.  I'd say toss the code and start again (it only does one or two things right), but if it came from a lecturer or tutor, change them and start again.  Why is it stuck using AWT?  Little excuse for that nowadays.

Comment: @mKorbel Look at the question closely.  There is no Swing or `JFrame`, just AWT & `Frame`.  Very low tech.

Answer (score 2):

`extends` is keyword which represents inheritence.

> Why the main method class is extends to Frame ? Why don't Frame being
>   created inside the main method or as the instance variable of class
>   QueenApl Frame something = new Frame(argument or none) ?

the difference is when you `extend Frame class` you acquire its methods in your class. i.e., you can override the methods declared in the frame class in QueenApl  class.

for better understanding here's a in-famous `Animal` example:

```
class Animal {
public void eat(){
//animal eat
}
class Dog extends Animal {
@override 
public void eat(){
//dog specific eat
}
}
}
```

Notice that you have overridden the eat method in Dog class to implement dog specific eat operations.

> 2.)By the way why getToolkit() can be used directly without append the classname. in front of it ? Is it because this method is in the class
>   Frame and since the main method class inherit Frame , we can use the
>   method directly ?

well that's because your `getToolKit()` method is inherited from your `Frame clas`s, thus you don't need to call it with an instance.

Comment: Why don't an extra class is created to inherit the Frame and override that particular method inside that class and create an object of that class inside the main method ?

Comment: @caramel1995 sorry i dint get you there, if you are asking why you need inheritence?? well, its because you need to genralize your objects. as in my example an Animal could be anything, a Dog, Cat, Sheep...

Comment: @caramel1995 It inherits it so it can override "paint".

Comment: e.g 
class someClass extends Frame{
   .
   .
   .
 //  override the Frame method here
}

public class mainClass{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    someClass = new someClass();
    //and so on
  }
}

Comment: Because your class QueenApl IS actually a Frame. It is an extension of a Frame, and other classes in your project can use it as such.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really have to extend Frame, it';s just convenient.
Compare your code to this code  which does not extend Frame. Instead, you need to have a Frame field.

calling methods like setSize() and getToolkit() now need to be prefixed by your Frame field, because **this** isn't a Frame any more. Your code does not need them because **this** is a frame, methods of non-private ancestor classes can be called by your class.

```
import java.net.*;    
import java.awt.*;

public class QueenApl { 
  Image card;
  Frame frame;

  public static void main(String[] args){
      QueenApl f = new QueenApl();
  }

  public QueenApl(){
    frame = new Frame();
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    try{
      URL u = new URL("file:/c:/windows/desktop/carn4.jpg");
      card=frame.getToolkit().getImage(u);
    } catch(MalformedURLException e){
      System.out.println("Error in URL!"); System.exit(1);
    } 
    frame.show();
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(card,120,50,frame);
  }   
}
```

Comment: How would the image be drawn if the class did not derive frame?

Comment: the last line of the constructor : frame.show() draws everything

Comment: How would he perform what is done in overridden "paint" without inheriting JFrame?

Answer (score 1):

It inherits JFrame so it can override the paint method, allowing the image "card" to be drawn to the screen. Without overriding the paint method, there would be no way of accessing the graphics object to draw to the JFrame.

The paint method comes with a java.awt.Graphics parameter, which will allow you to draw to the JFrame. Overriding the "paint" method is the only means by which you can acquire a Graphics class to draw to a JFrame.

"getToolkit" is inherited from JFrame, directly into your "QueenApl" class. Because of this, "getToolkit" is now technically a member of the "QueenApl" class. Therefore no member/class name  must be appended before the method call.

If you don't really understand what I mean when I say "inherits" or "extends", look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).